# How to flip normals with Geometry Nodes

Tags: node-editor, normals, geometry-nodes

I am trying to flip the normals of an object using geometry nodes.

I know that the flip faces node is supposed to do something like that but it does not seem to create the effect I want.

If anybody knows a way to flip an objects normals using nodes that would be much appreciated

Comment: unfortunately you didn't say what "effect" you want. Flip faces does indeed flip faces. like so: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2ctd.gif so please improve your question and tell us 1) what you want to achieve 2) what you have tried 3) what doesn't work

Comment: I am trying to acheive an inverted hull effect

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://www.blendernation.com/2020/02/28/daily-blender-tip-inverted-hull-toon-outline/

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: Try [Flip Faces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/flip_faces.html) node. My question is how to know and distinguish between flipped and not flipped faces.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

[image: result]

[image: node net]

You need to activate *Backface Culling* in the *outline* material:

[image: outline material]